# Is there any ways to capture mouse wheel event in AS3 Flex Air Desktop Application?

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, air, desktop-application, mousewheel

Is there any ways to capture mouse wheel event in AS3 Flex Air Desktop Application?

I am using FlashBuilder 4.7, FlexSDK 4.6 and Air 15.0

I tried below without success. There is no reaction or not smooth reaction(but not often).

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:WindowedApplication xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009" 
                       xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" 
                       xmlns:mx="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/mx"
                       applicationComplete="windowedapplication1_applicationCompleteHandler(event)"
                       mouseWheel="onMouseWheel(event)">

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            import mx.events.FlexEvent;         
            protected function windowedapplication1_applicationCompleteHandler(event:FlexEvent):void
            {
                systemManager.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, onMouseWheel);
                stage.addEventListener(MouseEvent.MOUSE_WHEEL, onMouseWheel);
            }

            private function onMouseWheel(e:MouseEvent):void{
                trace(e.type + " " + e.delta);
            }

        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <fx:Declarations>
        <!-- Place non-visual elements (e.g., services, value objects) here -->
    </fx:Declarations>
</s:WindowedApplication>
```

and -app.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" standalone="no"?>
<application xmlns="http://ns.adobe.com/air/application/15.0">
    <id>MouseTest</id>
    <filename>MouseTest</filename>
    <name>MouseTest</name>
    <versionNumber>0.0.0</versionNumber>
    <initialWindow>
        <content>[This value will be overwritten by Flash Builder in the output app.xml]</content>
        <autoOrients>false</autoOrients>
        <fullScreen>false</fullScreen>
        <visible>false</visible>
    </initialWindow>
</application>
```

Thanks

Comment: Does the window have the OS focus? I have noticed that AIR doesn't get hover events if the window doesn't have focus

Comment: yes...it is on focus...it can capture mouse down and mouse up events

Comment: Your code is fine, but to see the trace, you should debug your project not run it !

Comment: haha...of course i know that i should debug the project...even i wrote Alert.show(...)...also no action...thx

Comment: @MikeCheung Could you try to install [this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/vxti2gmsnshhcgt/mousewheel.air) (your code with labels) ?

Comment: yes...but the result is same as my code...
i installed and saw Air Version 15.0.0.356 and Label...
after i tried 10-20 times of mouse wheel down...label is changed to mouseWheel -3...and no action again....another 10-20 times up is changed to 3

Comment: I just tried it with Flex 4.6 AIR 3.9 on FDT, without adding the event listener to the stage and `systemManager` and just in the `WindowedApplication` tab and got the expected results: 3,-3,6,-6. every time my mousewheel goes one step forward or backward. You could either try to remove those event listeners or try to use a previous AIR version such as 14 to see if it might be a bug.

Answer (score 0):

Try creating a group with some content and have the mouse listener there.

In general mouse wheel works fine with flex components, not sure what is the issue with your code my guess is either you have nothing drawn on the screen to catch the mouse wheel events or that it shouldn't be added to the window application component.